# Cascading remove in JPA @OneToMany vs database cascade foreign key delete

Tags: java, jpa, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I'm seeing a lot of similar questions, but haven't found something conclusive that brings it together.

When using JPA, if you have a @OneToMany relation it can be specified to cascade the `REMOVE` operation. At the same time, foreign keys can be specified in the database with an action to take if the key base row gets deleted.

JPA example:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Child> children;
    // getters, setters...

}

@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = parent_id, nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;
    // getters, setters...

}
```

In the database, the `Child` table would then have a column `parent_id` with a foreign key constraint to the `Parent`'s `id` column.

Some actions possible on that foreign key constraint for cascading on delete are `delete`, `set to null` and `do nothing`. This gives the following combinations of scenarios.

```
       JPA | cascade | no cascade |
           | remove  | remove     |
DB FK      |         |            |
-----------+---------+------------|
delete     |    A    |     D      |
-----------+---------+------------|
set null   |    B    |     E      |
-----------+---------+------------|
do nothing |    C    |     F      |
-----------+---------+------------+
```

- A: Cascade remove call on parent in JPA, delete children in database on deletion of parent row they have a foreign key to.
- B: Cascade remove in JPA, set foreign key column in Child table to null in database on parent delete. The `nullable` in @JoinColumn and/or `optional` in `@ManyToOne` probably need to be true/false in this case.
- C: Cascade remove in JPA, do nothing in the database on a foreign key removal.
- D: Don't cascade remove in JPA, cascade delete of parent in database.
- E: Don't cascade remove in JPA, set foreign key column in Child table to null in database on parent delete.
- F: Don't cascade remove in JPA, do nothing n the database on a foreign key removal.

So, questions about this.

**Which of these scenarios leads to exceptions?** If figure C would. If you remove a `Parent` instance via an `EntityManager`, the call is first done on that instance and then cascaded to the `Child` instances in the collection property. But trying to remove a parent from the database without first removing related children leads to foreign key violations. Is this correct? Are there other faulty scenarios? Woud A cause issues with trying to remove entities from persistence that have already been removed from the underlying DB?

**Which leave the EntityManager cache in an inconsistent state with the database?** I reckon it's D and E. In these cases you would have to call `remove()` for the instances in the child list yourself.

**Which setup should you use to enforce data consistency in both the JPA layer and on the database?** Will A do the trick? I think B could also work since the database itself will set the foreign key columns to null on deleting a parent (no longer violating constraints) and JPA can then remove the child instances.

Answer (score 1):

- **Exception Scenarios:**

I think B, and E leads to exceptions too, since the foreign key field not is nullable.

When updating its value with null, there an exception will be raised.

- **To** **Achieve Consistency** between JPA and database:

I think using A, or F will achieve it. In both of them the same actions will be taken on the both layers.